# iOS: Best way for subview of subview of ... to talk to parenting controller

Tags: ios, delegates, subview

I've been wondering the best way to do this for a while now...

Currently in order to get a subview of a subview of a UIViewController to send a message to the UIViewController, I'll have the second level subview communicate to it's parent subview using a delegate, and then set up another delegate for the first level subview to communicate with the UIViewController.

If I'm only having subviews talk to their parents, I suppose I could just create a property for the parent in the child, set it to weak, and send messages that way.

Is there another, better way to do this?

Comment: Could you go into more detail of what the view needs to communicate to the view controller?  More details would provide more clarity on what the appropriate solution should be. :)

Comment: Specifically, the case is usually an embedded button, but I want the controller to perform the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a code connection? Just control-click the button in the storyboard and drag it into your view controller?

Then it should look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)goToVC3:(id)sender {
    // whatever you wanna do when button is pressed
}
```

There's also a manual option. Say you want to do something with a button you have just created and added to your view. Well, just add this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(doSomething)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (void)doSomething
{
    // whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I'll try this! This sounds exactly like what I want. Just instead of self.button, it would be something like self.subview.subview.button?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Wherever it's located, this will work as long as you can get a reference to it.

Comment: @RyJ If my answer did what you want, please accept it. Otherwise, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but the ideal way in your example is utilizing the [responder chain](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/the-amazing-responder-chain/).

I'll spare a detailed explanation here, because the linked article explains it all in its glorious detail, but the main point is to decouple your button's action with the code that gets executed for it.  You could, as you propose, use delegation, but what if you insert another view in the hierarchy?  Now, you have to propagate the delegation through 'another' view, which means another view having implementation details for passing the event. Yuck.

With the responder chain, the system will walk the chain of objects that are eligible for responding until it finds an object that implements the desired behavior.  This is exactly what we want!  Your button's action should then call code something like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(doFoo:) 
                                           to:nil 
                                         from:nil
                                     forEvent:nil];
```

Comment: And then whoever responds to doFoo: (in the responder chain) will perform the action?

Comment: @RyJ Yessir, but as far as I can tell from the article, this is more of an OSX thing. I say that because I don't think you need to resort to this option. It's a little unsafe and a little esoteric because like you said, whoever responds to this first will perform it.

Comment: @doctordoder Not exactly.  The responder chain is alive and well on iOS.  It's roots are in the OS X file menus, but the most common practice for using the responder chain on iOS is for `UITextField` and dismissing the keyboard.

Comment: @doctordoder Yes.  In the example above you would replace `doFoo:` with `resignFirstResponder`.

Comment: @WayneHartman I always just did `[self.view endEditing:YES];` That must use the responder chain.

Comment: @doctordoder That's another way of doing it, but I wouldn't be surprised if under-the-covers it's walking the responder chain.